# await slowest of two async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
public async Task RunTwo()
{
    DoThing(1);
    DoThing(2);
}

public async Task DoThing(int order)
{
    // do stuff... asynchronously... woooOooOo
}
```

I want to run `DoThing(1)` and `DoThing(2)` at the same time, but not exit the method until they are both completed.

I can't do `await DoThing(1)` then `await DoThing(2)` because that will process them sequentially (I think..)

Maybe I can do something like `await new Task(() => DoThing(1); ...`, but there's probably a better way.

Comment: Side note: duplicate answers your question in the body of your post... Title seem to be asking something very different (like `var t1=DoSlow();await DoFast();await t1;`) but it's unclear if you actually care to explicitly wait for one differently than other - feel free to ping me if I got your post wrong ([edit] to clarify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) for this.

So for you it will be:

```
public async Task RunTwo() 
{
    await Task.WhenAll(DoThing(1), DoThing(2));
}
```